# IPython - running a script with %run command - saved to which folder?

Tags: python, ipython

I'm in IPython and want to run a simple python script that I've saved in a file called "test.py".

I'd like to use the `%run test.py` command to execute it inside IPython, but I don't know to which folder I need to save my test.py.

Also, how can I change that default folder to something else, for example C:\Users\user\foldername ?

I tried with the .ipython folder (original installation folder) but that's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
import os
filepath = 'C:\\Users\\user\\foldername'
os.chdir(filepath)
%run test.py
```

Comment: `%cd foldername` should do the same thing.  `%pwd` to see the current dir, `%ls` to get a directory listing. `%run foldername/test.py` might also work.  If I'm using a directory a lot, I'll `cd` to it before starting `ipython`.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful

Answer (score 0):

`%run myprogram` works for Python scripts/programs.

To run any arbitrary programs, use `!` as a prefix, e.g. `!myprogram`.

Many common shell commands/programs (`cd`, `ls`, `less`, ...) are also registered as IPython magic commands (run via `%cd`, `%ls`, ...), and also have registered aliases, so you can directly run them without any prefix, just as `cd`, `ls`, `less`, ...